# Wifi problem in downloading software packages Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, downloads

In my Ubuntu 12.04 sony vaio when trying to download packages from Ubuntu repositories wifi speed is very slow. Internet works fine for other downloads/browsing. I tried with changing the download server but no change. Getting a download speed <1kbps.

Comment: I have tried with LAN connection also,again showing the same problem.I couldn't get my ubuntu 12.04 updated.Download will start at higher speeds at about 300kbps and after some download about 20-30 mb speed will be reduced to 1 kbps.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is running the commands below in sequence:

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
sudo iwconfig
```

Basically, it turns of the power management system to mess with the wifi adapter. You may try other [Ubuntu wireless problem fixes](http://www.htpcbeginner.com/how-to-fix-wireless-problems-in-ubuntu-1204-precise-pangolin/) listed in this page. For me they did not work.